# Efficient way to calculate eigen-values of a 2x2 matrix

Tags: dsp-core, fixed-point, eigendecomposition

I'm working on an algorithm that works based on finding the eigen-values of a 2x2 complex covariance matrix. However, from a fixed-point implementation point of view, finding eigen-value of a matrix is computationally extensive. What is the best way to implement such computation in a more efficient manner?

Comment: You mean something less computational less expensive than solving a quadratic equation?

Comment: Yes, since such process must be repeated for each frequency.

Comment: would calculating the eigenvalues at each frequency in parallel be an option?

Comment: More efficient than what?  Please **edit your question** to show the algorithm you're currently using.  Note that I don't think you're going to get it faster than quadratic, but there's a lot of contributers here who know fixed-point numerical tricks that may be of help.  While you're editing your question, please also tell us what your expected range of eigenvalues are, and how precisely you need to calculate them -- that has a bearing on any algorithm that can trade off speed for accuracy.

Comment: you use the tag [tag:eigendecomposition]. Do you really just need the eigenvalues, or do you need to find the eigenvalue decomposition? Those are two different problems, and the first one can be a side product of the second. Anyway, If you think that solving a quadratic equation is computationally hard: either you're not telling us everything, or you might be not having a very complete view of what is hard in your system.

Comment: Also, eigenvalue problems with potentially small Eigenvalues (remember what the entries on your diagonal physically represent) is **the** example for "problems that stay error-bound much nicer if done in floating point"; even just the trivial solution to your eigenvalue question (doing this in my head: let your autocov matrix be $M=(a,b;b^*,c)$, then your solution to $\det(M-\lambda I) =0$ is something like $\lambda = (a+b)/2\pm\sqrt{\lvert b\rvert^2 + a^2 + ac +c^2}$) requires you to find the square root of a number – something that's pretty nice on floating point, and not as nice on fixed.